# google maps api geocoding is less precise than manual search, why?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

i am using a php script (followed this tutorial http://www.bitconsultants.net/2010/geocoding-with-google-maps-and-the-zend-framework/) to get the latitude and longitude of different adresses,

the problem is that if i manually search an address in google maps it gives me the right location, 
while using the php script, the json response from google is even 500meters away from the manual search result, which makes it kind of pointless for my needs...

i am passing the address in this format

```
$address = "{$data['street']}, {$data['postcode']}, {$data['city']}, {$data['province']}";
```

and i am passing google a key

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found out why, **don't use php urlencode()** on the $address, it does something strange with "," and maybe other stuff, so google doesn't understands well your url

Answer (score 1):

Are your addresses really well formed? Could you please give a concrete example?

Such difference could occur if the postal address is not found at given city or town and Google tries to partially match the given address. See *partial_match* on [API documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/hu-HU/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Results).

Also: unfortunately the link you gave above does not work here ("Forbidden" error).

Comment: hmm i just tried again the link, it works from my workplace... anyways an example would be searching this "Via Albalonga, 6 00183 Roma RM" , google maps manual search gives me 41.442726,12.392578 while the script gives me 41.881206,12.5137996

Comment: here is the link the script opens http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Via%20Albalonga,%206%2000183%20Roma%20RM&region=It&language=it am i using an old link or something?

Comment: you were right!!! i switched to the other url http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false and i do get partial_match, however the same address manually is ok, using the script sometimes i even end up on another street nearby an intersection, i can't understand why